# C# saving ini file using ConfigurationBuilder

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to read and write simple ini files using `ConfigurationBuilder`.

Here is my code for reading (parsing):

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration {
  public static class ExtensionMethods {
    public static ImmutableDictionary<string, string?>? ParseIni(this ConfigurationBuilder _, string filename, out string? err) {
      try {
        if (!File.Exists(filename)) {
          err = $"File missing";
          return null;
        }

        if (new ConfigurationBuilder().AddIniFile(filename, optional: false).Build() is not ConfigurationRoot configuration) {
          err = "Parsing failed";
          return null;
        }

        err = null;
        return configuration.AsEnumerable().ToImmutableDictionary();

      } catch (Exception ex) {
        err = ex.ToString();
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can now do:

```
var dict = new ConfigurationBuilder().ParseIni(filename, out var _);
var someVal = dict[somekey];
```

I now need a matching writing function with the signature:

```
    public static bool WriteIni(this ConfigurationBuilder _, string filename, ImmutableDictionary<string, string?> map) { ... }
```

(I don't need to worry about sections for now)

However I can't find any docs or examples on how to create and then write an ini file from a key/val dictionary ? is it possible ?

Comment: Sure. But not with `ConfigurationBuilder`, which isn't equipped to write settings, it only reads them. Of course there is no shortage of code online that promises to write .ini files for you, and it's easy enough to do yourself if you don't care about sections, but the MS configuration system won't do it for you.

Comment: what about `Configuration.Save` ? is that a different mechanism to ConfigurationBuilder ? can it be used for this ?

Comment: It is in fact an entirely different mechanism and supports only the old-style XML configuration files, so no. It's not like writing key-value pairs is particularly hard (`File.WriteAllLines("..", dictionary.Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}={kvp.Value}"))`, some additional care required for escaping if you have "interesting" value).